# Is there anyone who has knowledge/experience on bit bucket with salesforce

Tags: sourcecontrol, bitbucket

My requirement is when I do any changes to my sandbox then I can also fetch to my local system and can commit those changes to feature branch.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. The community is here to help in an open Q&A manner, with all necessary details shared here. In addition, you need to demonstrate that you have researched your requirement and indicate where you are stuck. The community isn't here to provide whole solutions. I recommend you [edit] the question to show your research and state where you are stuck, otherwise it is likely to be closed without answer.

Comment: @kavya For your own privacy, kindly avoid including your personal contact info in your posts. Also check [ask] to have a better idea about the format of this community

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with git, then there's nothing special about BitBucket. It works the same as GitHub, GitLab, etc. Simply [Enable Source Tracking in Sandboxes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_setup_enable_source_tracking_sandboxes.htm) (Setup > Dev Hub > Enable Source Tracking in Developer and Developer Pro Sandboxes), then refresh or create a new Sandbox and authorize SFDX to that org. You can then use force:source:push and force:source:pull to sync changes between the Sandbox and your local copy of the repo, which you can then use normal git commands (git add, git commit, git push, git pull) using BitBucket.

Comment: The places where they are different are pull request handling and automation, but these don't necessarily come into the picture in this scenario. It is worth noting that `.forceignore` should be set up to avoid polluting your local workspace with metadata that isn't relevant.